# What ClassLoader does Class.forName use by default?

Tags: java, classloader

I had the impression that `Class.forName(String className)` used the `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` to load the class but apparently that isn't the case.

Hence my question, **what ClassLoader does `Class.forName` use by default? is it the `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`**?

and what's the difference between `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` and `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It uses the caller's classloader. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name.  Invoking this method is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> Class.forName(className, true, currentLoader)
> ```
>
> where currentLoader denotes the defining class loader of the current class.

Comment: So you mean it is neither one of them ? unless the class was loaded from one of them?

Comment: @AdelBoutros: Exactly. It's whatever loaded the calling class.

Answer (score 2):

It uses invokers class loader. The source code of the forName(), :

```
public static Class<?> forName(String className) 
                throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return forName0(className, true, ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader());
    }
```

And the  getCallerClassLoader() is :

```
static ClassLoader getCallerClassLoader() {
        // NOTE use of more generic Reflection.getCallerClass()
        Class caller = Reflection.getCallerClass(3);
        // This can be null if the VM is requesting it
        if (caller == null) {
            return null;
        }
        // Circumvent security check since this is package-private
        return caller.getClassLoader0();
    }
```

And the description of this method is :

```
// Returns the invoker's class loader, or null if none.
```